# C++ dynamic_cast with a C# com visible object

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop, atlcom

I have an old COM component in C++/ATL (Active Template Library) which uses a dynamic_cast to convert a COM interface into the C++ class which implementes the interface.

If the conversion is not possible, the dynamic_cast returns a NULL pointer.

I now have a new implementation of the same COM interface in a com-visible C# component.

When the dynamic_cast operator is applied to the COM object from C#, I would expect it to return NULL, but in fact it throws an exception (I have no idea what exception).

I can certainly wrap the dynamic_cast in a try/catch block, but is this normal behavior?

Comment: Yes, the COM Callable Wrapper is NOT the class you're trying to get. You'll need to expose any internal functionality on a different interface and do a `QueryInterface` for it. Moreover the CCW may not be a C++ object and thus valid to cast in the first place.

Comment: It is quite clear to me that dynamic_cast must fail. The question is why does it throw an exception instead of returning NULL, which as far as I know is the documented behavior. The underlying object is not C++, but the CCW is necessarily an unmanaged object which supports the same calling convention. That apparently is not enough for the dynamic_cast operator. I find that surprising.

Comment: If I was to guess it's because you're trying to access RTTI across modules which AFAIK is undefined behavior. That said without knowing exactly what exception is thrown and what the error console said I can't be sure.

Comment: I can catch all exceptions with catch(...), but as far as I know, there is no way in C++ to determine the type of the exception which was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I think MGetz has given the correct information.

dynamic_cast relies on Run-Time Type Information (RTTI). This implies that it can only work in a homogeneous project where all code is compiled with the same compiler (using the same compiler options).

If I disable RTTI, I get

```
warning C4541: 'dynamic_cast' used on polymorphic type 'IMyInterfaceName' with /GR-; 
unpredictable behavior may result
```

Effectively, we can extend this to say that dynamic_cast on the COM callable wrapper (CCW) of a C# object also results in unpredictable behavior.

Better to avoid dynamic_cast altogether.